# Trying to understand the asynchrouny with a big amount of different function calls

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous, wininet

I've started learing an asynchronous aproach, and 
encountered a problem, help me with it.

The purpose is: get from somewhere a `char` data, and after that do something with it(using as text on the button, in my case). The code, that is pinned below is very slow. The most slowiest moment is a data getting: the fact is that the `get(int id)` function loads data from internet via `WinInet`(synchronously), sending the Post methods, and returning the answer.

```
void some_func()
{
for(int i(0);i<10;i++)
   for(int q(0);q<5;q++)
     {
       char data[100];
       strcpy(data, get(i,q)); // i, q - just some identifier data

       button[5*i+(q+1)]=new Button(data);
     }
}
```

**The first question:**

How should it be solved(generaly, I mean, if `get` has nothing to do with the internet, but runs slow)? I have only one, stupid idea: run `get` in every separate thread. If it's the right way - how should I do that? Cause, it's wrong to, created 50 threads call from each the `get` function. 50 `get` functions?

**Second Question**

How to realize it with `WinInet`? Have red MSDN, but it too hardly for me, as for newer, maybe you explain it more simlier?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  If it takes a long time to fetch one datum from a remote host, there's nothing you can do on your end to make it happen any faster.  The question is, what _else_ could your program do (maybe, in some other thread) while it is waiting for the datum to be returned.

Comment: @jameslarge, I'm just send the `post` request, and read resonse(few bytes) via `InternetReadFile` in the `get` function. It shouldn't be sooo(abount 1 second in my case) slow

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't be so slow, but if you don't control the server on the other end and the routers in between, then there may be nothing you can do to speed it up.  You put the `[multithreading]` tag and the `[asynchronous]` tag on your question.  Why?  You can't use multithreading or async IO in a client program to make the server go faster, but you _can_ use either one of them to let your client to do other things while it waits for the server to respond.  What other things are there for your client to do while it waits?

Answer (score 0):

for asynchronous programming you need create some object which will be maintain state - in current case `i` and `q` must be not local variables of function but members of object, mandatory reference count to object. and usual file(socket) handle , etc.

function `some_func()` must have another pattern. it must be member function of object. and it must not call asynchronous `get` in loop. after call `get` it must just exit. when asynchronous operation, initiated by `get`, will be finished - some your callback must be called (if failed initiate asynchronous operation you need yourself just call this callback with error code). in callback you will be have pointer to your object  and using it - call `some_func()`. so `some_func()` must at begin handle result of previous `get` call - check for error, handle received data, if no error. than adjust object state (in your case `i` and `q`) and if need - call `get` again. and for initiated all this - need first time call `get` direct:

```
begin -> get() -> .. callback .. -> some_func() -> exit
          ^                             ┬
          └─────────────────────────────┘
```

some demo example (with asynchronous read file)

```
struct SOME_OBJECT 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER _ByteOffset;
    HANDLE _hFile;
    LONG _dwRef;
    int _i, _q;

    SOME_OBJECT()
    {
        _i = 0, _q = 0;
        _dwRef = 1;
        _ByteOffset.QuadPart = 0;
        _hFile = 0;
    }

    void beginGet();

    void DoSomething(PVOID pvData, DWORD_PTR cbData)
    {
        DbgPrint("DoSomething<%u,%u>(%x, %p)\n", _i, _q, cbData, pvData);
    }

    // some_func
    void OnComplete(DWORD dwErrorCode, PVOID pvData, DWORD_PTR cbData)
    {
        if (dwErrorCode == NOERROR)
        {
            DoSomething(pvData, cbData);

            if (++_q == 5)
            {
                _q = 0;

                if (++_i == 10)
                {
                    return ;
                }
            }

            _ByteOffset.QuadPart += cbData;

            beginGet();
        }
        else
        {
            DbgPrint("OnComplete - error=%u\n", dwErrorCode);
        }
    }

    ~SOME_OBJECT()
    {
        if (_hFile) CloseHandle(_hFile);
    }

    void AddRef() { InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef); }

    void Release() { if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this; }

    ULONG Create(PCWSTR FileName);
};

struct OPERATION_CTX : OVERLAPPED 
{
    SOME_OBJECT* _pObj;
    BYTE _buf[];

    OPERATION_CTX(SOME_OBJECT* pObj) : _pObj(pObj)
    {
        pObj->AddRef();
        hEvent = 0;
    }

    ~OPERATION_CTX()
    {
        _pObj->Release();
    }

    VOID CALLBACK CompletionRoutine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD_PTR dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        _pObj->OnComplete(dwErrorCode, _buf, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);

        delete this;
    }

    static VOID CALLBACK _CompletionRoutine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, OVERLAPPED* lpOverlapped)
    {
        static_cast<OPERATION_CTX*>(lpOverlapped)->CompletionRoutine(RtlNtStatusToDosError(dwErrorCode), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }

    void CheckResult(BOOL fOk)
    {
        if (!fOk)
        {
            ULONG dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

            if (dwErrorCode != ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                CompletionRoutine(dwErrorCode, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    void* operator new(size_t cb, size_t ex)
    {
        return ::operator new(cb + ex);
    }

    void operator delete(PVOID pv)
    {
        ::operator delete(pv);
    }
};

ULONG SOME_OBJECT::Create(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        _hFile = hFile;

        if (BindIoCompletionCallback(hFile, OPERATION_CTX::_CompletionRoutine, 0)) 
        {
            return NOERROR;
        }
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

void SOME_OBJECT::beginGet()
{
    const ULONG cbRead = 0x1000;

    if (OPERATION_CTX* ctx = new(cbRead) OPERATION_CTX(this))
    {
        ctx->Offset = _ByteOffset.LowPart;
        ctx->OffsetHigh = _ByteOffset.HighPart;
        ctx->CheckResult(ReadFile(_hFile, ctx->_buf, cbRead, 0, ctx));
    }
}

void ADemo(PCWSTR FileName)
{
    if (SOME_OBJECT* pObj = new SOME_OBJECT)
    {
        if (!pObj->Create(FileName))
        {
            pObj->beginGet();
        }
        pObj->Release();
    }
}
```